# Error: Interface 'Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface' not found Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, cups

Использую данный плагин для печати

[cups](https://packagist.org/packages/smalot/cups-ipp)

Работало все хорошо, теперь перенес код на другой комп, развернул проект, все поставил, и начал получать такую ошибку

```
Error: Interface 'Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface' not found
```

Все пакеты стоят, не могу понять в чем проблема. Может кто подскажет?

Answer (score 0):

Надо было также перенести composer.lock и на другом компе просто composer install сделать, чтобы он подтянул версии, которые в локе указаны.